# Zip of folder in C:\ fails with Access is denied, cannot open file

Tags: windows-10

I have a directory in C:\ that I wish to zip. My user owns the directory and files inside it and I have modified the security settings so `Everyone` has `Full control`, my user also has `Full control`.

I have no idea what I have to do so that I can Zip the directory and it's contents.

Comment: Please click [edit] and enter the exact command you entered and the exact response from Windows. Also, you might try installing the Open Source 7-zip app https://www.7-zip.org which has a GUI and is easy to work with. Make sure to specify the destination for the ZIP file is somewhere you have access to, such as c:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Downloads\

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a comment if I could since I don't have enough information to say this is your solution, but make sure that the destination .zip file is being written to a path you can write to. The error might sound like it is telling you that you can't open the folder to zip it when it actually means you can't create the output file.